# Nuxt3 dynamic component loading style conflict problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 3 application where I want to load 2 different Header components for Mobile and Desktop.
I have `Header.vue` and `MobileHeader.vue` and I want to load them respectively for desktop and mobile.
this is my layout code:

```js
<template>
  <MobileHeader v-if="isMobile" />

  <Header v-else />
  
  <slot />
</template>
<script setup>
const MobileHeader = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('~/components/layout/MobileHeader.vue'));
const Header = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('~/components/layout/Header.vue'));
</script>
```

`Header.vue` and `MobileHeader.vue` both have their own scss files which is imported like this:

```js
<style lang="scss">
@import "/assets/scss/components/layout/mobile-header";
</style>
```

The problem is both `mobile-header.scss` and `header.scss` files are loaded in page and obviously I want them to load only if their respective component is loaded.

how can I achieve this?

ps1. I disabled component autoloading in `nuxt.config.ts`
ps2. I tried importing components the usual way but it didn't work too.

```js
import MobileHeader from '~/components/layout/MobileHeader.vue';
```

Comment: This is how styles work. Proceed from this. Use scoped styles or specific selectors to avoid conflicts. Generally it's bad UX anyway when desktop/mobile mode isn't changeable until the page is reloaded

Comment: The problem is style from a component which has v-if="false" is loaded in the page. and by the way, its not about ux. its called Adaptive (instead of Responsive) to load completely different layouts/pages/components for mobile and desktop and its a common practice.

Comment: Again, this is  how component styles work in Vue. You'd have problems unloading styles which are in conflict in case v-if condition is dynamic. What you see this is the expected behaviour and not specific to Nuxt afaik. The UX part is that a user can switch to "desktop mode" in mobile browser and vice versa in desktop browser. Most websites provide this without page reload, despite this is an edge case

Comment: I figured it out. please check my answer. On the UX part, with Adaptive design, you are not bound to making 2 designs compatible code-wise and more importantly mobile users  dont have to download desktop styles/js and vice versa. its a huge difference at least in unused css/js!

Comment: probably reading this will help you to understand as Im bad at describing this:
https://www.wix.com/blog/responsive-vs-adaptive-design

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. for future references and anyone who has the same question, here it goes.
I changed the code like this and it works:

```js
<template>
  <Header />
  <slot />
</template>
<script setup>

const {isMobile} = useDevice();

const Header = defineAsyncComponent(() => isMobile ? import('~/components/layout/MobileHeader.vue') : import('~/components/layout/Header.vue'));
```